# Значение подходящей под регулярное выражение части строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Есть регулярка `/^\/stats (.*)/i`. Как получить значение того, что попадает под (.*)?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `gsub`, с блоком, из которого возвращать `$1`:

```
"/stats take me".gsub(/^\/stats (.*)/i){ $1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если цель - получить значение захватывающей подмаски №1, достаточно использовать один из 4 следующих способов:

```
s = "/stats my string"
rx = /^\/stats (.*)/i
# RegExp#match
rx.match(s) {|m|
    puts m[1] # => my string
    # или
    puts m.captures[0] # => my string
}
# String[RegExp, #]
puts s[rx,1] # => my string
# String#scan(RegExp)
puts s.scan(rx).last.first # => my string
```

См. [демо](http://ideone.com/IDj4Ho)

Comment: такое случается, перцы мало когда отзываются )

Answer (score 0):

Следует использовать метод [`str[regexp, capture] → new_str or nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), передав в качестве первого параметра регулярку, а в качестве второго -- номер группы.

```
irb> "/Stats 123"[/^\/stats (.*)/i, 1]
=> "123"
irb> "/ЫЫЫЫЫ 123"[/^\/stats (.*)/i, 1]
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с версии `1.9` в руби появился возможность указывать имя переменной, в которую нужно поместить результат. Например:

```
/^\/stats (?<var_name>.*)/i =~ '/stats zzee'
var_name # => 'zzee'
```

**ЗАМЕТКА:** Имейте ввиду, метод `#=~` должен быть вызван у объекта класса `Regexp`, а не строки, т.е. регулярное выражение должно идти по тексту первым. В противном случае переменная задана не будет.